# How to call a method from another class that uses an interface with a parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a method (BeginCommand) from another class. The method is using an interface(IAudioRecorder) and has a parameter (recorder). My class is RecorderViewModel.

```
public void BeginCommand(IAudioRecorder recorder)
{ 
    beginRecordingCommand = new RelayCommand(BeginRecording, () => recorder.RecordingState == RecordingState.Stopped || recorder.RecordingState == RecordingState.Monitoring);
}
```

Over in my other class here is how I'm trying to call it:

```
var audiorecorder = new AudioRecorder();
var recordviewmodel = new RecorderViewModel(audiorecorder);
recordviewmodel.BeginCommand();
```

If I remove the interface and parameter (IAudioRecorder recorder) from the BeginCommand method it will work, but how do I call it with the interface/parameter. It's telling me there is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter... I'm not sure what parameters to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell (with your description) what's going on here, however I suspect you may just be able to do the following:

```
  recordviewmodel.BeginCommand(audiorecorder);
```

Assuming `audiorecorder` implements the `IAudioRecorder` Interface.

Comment: Good to see you up and about after your fall. +1

Comment: Sir, your spidey senses were correct! Thank you. Most of the time I don't know what's going on myself. Just googling and stackoverflowing the day away. I have a wpf application that is using a binding command in a button. I need to execute the command from code behind without pushing the button. That's what I'm trying to achieve here (i think).